# Loop through subitems in menustrip

Tags: c#, menustrip

Well i've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380730/foreach-every-subitem-in-a-menustrip):

```
private IEnumerable<ToolStripMenuItem> GetItems(ToolStripMenuItem item)
{
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem dropDownItem in item.DropDownItems)
    {
        if (dropDownItem.HasDropDownItems)
        {
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem subItem in GetItems(dropDownItem))
                yield return subItem;
        }
        yield return dropDownItem;
    }
}

private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ToolStripMenuItem> allItems = new List<ToolStripMenuItem>();
    foreach (ToolStripMenuItem toolItem in menuStrip1.Items)
    {
        allItems.Add(toolItem);
        MessageBox.Show(toolItem.Text);
        allItems.AddRange(GetItems(toolItem));
    }
}
```

but i only get `File`, `Edit`, `View`

[image]

i need to reach `Export` (see the figure) and its `subitem`, and maybe change the visibility of `Word` for example.

NOTE: the `form` changes the `menustrip` item dynamically thats why i need to loop through them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on the details you provided you can use linq as

```
var exportMenu=allItems.FirstOrDefault(t=>t.Text=="Export");
if(exportMenu!=null)
{
    foreach(ToolStripItem item in exportMenu.DropDownItems) // here i changed the var item to ToolStripItem
    {
         if(item.Text=="Word") // as you mentioned in the requirements
              item.Visible=false; // or any variable that will set the visibility of the item
    }
}
```

hope that this will help you

regards

Comment: well, i can't test it, there's blue line under `item.Text` and `item.Visible` "object does not contain a definition for text, Visible...."

Comment: this because the compiler didn't know what is the type of item in the foreach loop, instead of (var item) put (ToolStripItem item) and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all the menu items (ToolStripMenuItem instances) in your MenuStrip use the following code (I assume the MenuStrip name is menuStrip1)

```
// Get all the top menu items, e.g. File , Edit and View
List<ToolStripMenuItem> allItems = new List<ToolStripMenuItem>();
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuStrip1.Items)
{
   // For each of the top menu items, get all sub items recursively
    allItems.AddRange(GetItems(item)); 
}
```

Comment: Terrible post. Method `GetItems` doesn't exist

Comment: The method `GetItems` *does* exist.